# Do I need to always have a server running to make every command after starting an app?

Tags: python, django

I'am reading a book Python Crash Course 2nd Edition 3rd project, creating a django web app.

It's said that to start an app I need to have the server running in other terminal tab.

In the first tab:
`python manage.py runserver`

And in the second tab:
`python manage.py startapp learning_logs`

And after these manipulations I need to further do those: defining a model, activating a model, and making migration, etc.

**Do I need to have a server running to make other commands after starting an app? Or do I only need it running to start an app?**

So for example, do I need to have server running when further making a migration?

`python manage.py makemigrations learning_logs`

Comment: You don't need `runserver` for any of mentioned commands. `startapp` generates boilerplate code and structure, it has no idea that there is something up and running. You need `runserver` to see how your project works in browser which happens _after_ doing some work like creating new app or making migrations.

Comment: @IvanStarostin thank you. In book it was said that I need to have server running to start an app for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the server running to perform actions like making migrations. You can run management commands independently of whether the server is running or not. Feel free to go ahead and execute the following command:

**python manage.py makemigrations learning_logs**

This command will generate the necessary migration files based on the models you've defined in your learning_logs app.

Remember, while some commands don't require the server to be running, others like **runserver, collectstatic, or test** do. So, if you need the server running for a particular task, you'll see it in the command's output or documentation.